# Writing a script that will calculate the total number of text boxes in a pdf that countain a specific text

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I am creating a monthly data collection sheet where each day a staff member would enter a letter from a defined list of possible values. In this case, they are capital letters "I" "V" "P" "F" and "R." At the bottom of the pdf I want to have a box that will total the number of days a certain letter was entered. For example, if 10 out of 31 days in the month they entered an "I" I want it to auto calculate that sum.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRHMX.png)

Answer (score 0):

As an example, I used the below script to calculate the number of boxes with "V" entered.

```
var total = 0;
for(var i=1; i<=31; i++) {
    if(this.getField("B"+i).valueAsString=="V") total++;
}
event.value = total;
```